# Need help for mapping dynamic data with nginx

Tags: nginx

i have a content like this ( can be stored in a text file or database or etc):

```
[
  {
      "site_slug": "/site1",
      "site_url": "http://site1.com"
  }
]
```

i want nginx can read the data and map the location path with key: "site_slug" and redirect to "site_url"
is it possible? could you give me some keywords for googling?

Comment: Nginx has a [`map`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map) directive that can import a file. But you will need to reformat the data and restart Nginx whenever it changes.

Comment: @RichardSmith, you saved my day!. thank you a lot!